# An apparent error with Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: polynomials, series-expansion

I am on 11.0.1.0

`SeriesCoefficient[ChebyshevU[n,x],{x,0,m}]` returns

```
Piecewise[{{((-1/2)^m*Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[3/2+m]*Pochhammer[-n,m]*Pochhammer[2+n,m])
  /(m!*Gamma[(1+m-n)/2]*Gamma[(3+m+n)/2]*Pochhammer[3/2,m]), m >= 0}}, 0]
```

On the other hand,

```
With[{n=7},Sum[(((-1/2)^m*Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[3/2+m]*Pochhammer[-n,m]*Pochhammer[2+n,m])
  /(m!*Gamma[(1+m-n)/2]*Gamma[(3+m+n)/2]*Pochhammer[3/2,m]))x^m,{m,0,n}]]
```

gives `-x+10 x^3-24 x^5+16 x^7`, while `ChebyshevU[7,x]` is `-8 x+80 x^3-192 x^5+128 x^7`, and more generally for all `n` that I tried the correct answer is `n+1` times the answer given by the above `SeriesCoefficient` command.

Why is this `n+1` absent??

Comment: Seems to be off in V13.3.1, too. But this works: `SeriesCoefficient[ChebyshevU[n, x], {x, 0, m}, Assumptions -> n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers]`

Comment: Generally speaking, wrong results should be reported to WRI, not here.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you! What is WRI?

Comment: WRI is short for Wolram Research Inc., the maker of Mathematica

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh I see. But I have no idea how to report this there.

Comment: Reported (Tech Support CASE: 5072905)

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks a lot!

Comment: In Mathematica, select the menu command Help > Give Feedback... and it will take you to the webpage for making a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

coef1[m_] = SeriesCoefficient[ChebyshevU[n, x], {x, 0, m}]
```

[image]

As you concluded, the coefficients are off by a factor of `(n+1)`

```
Assuming[-1 < x < 1,
 Sum[coef1[m] x^m, {m, 0, Infinity}] ==
    ChebyshevU[n, x]/(n + 1) //
   FunctionExpand // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

As Michael E2 pointed out, by requiring `n` to be a nonnegative integer,

```
coef2[m_] = SeriesCoefficient[ChebyshevU[n, x], {x, 0, m},
  Assumptions -> n ∈ NonNegativeIntegers]
```

[image]

For `n` even

```
Assuming[{-1 < x < 1, n ∈ NonNegativeIntegers, Mod[n, 2] == 0},
 Sum[coef2[m] x^m, {m, 0, n, 2}] ==
    ChebyshevU[n, x] //
   FunctionExpand // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

For `n` odd

```
Assuming[{-1 < x < 1, n ∈ NonNegativeIntegers, Mod[n, 2] == 1},
 Sum[coef2[m] x^m, {m, 1, n, 2}] ==
    ChebyshevU[n, x] //
   FunctionExpand // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```